# How i must understand this sentry log ? 200 and 404 right after that

Tags: javascript, sentry

Sorry for this simple question, but i need help.

I have a project with connected sentry.io. It's working fine but some days ago I got this error log:

[image: part of sentry log]

I see request with 200 code, but 404 error code right behind them. What does it mean?

1. 200 is mean nothing, and my xnr request was 404.
2. Xnr request and 404 request are different requests. But for some reason i can't see URL of 404 request

If the second option is right how can i get request url?

Thanks for your atention.

Comment: Maybe some explanation in [the first couple of paragraphs here](https://gsitecrawler.com/articles/error-404-200.asp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing, I'm understand that second option is right.

Failed request may be sent anytime before error, not in closest breadcrumb.